# NSFetchRequest only returns results sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm answering my own question on this one. I won't accept it until I see as much other answers as possible.

For the past couple of days I've been struggling with the below code

```
- (id)fetchUniqueEntity:(Class)entityClass
              withValue:(id)value
            fromContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
            insertIfNil:(BOOL)insertIfNil {
    if(!value) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *entityUniqueIdentifierKey = [entityClass performSelector:@selector(uniqueIdentifierKey)];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", entityUniqueIdentifierKey, value];

    NSArray *entities = [self fetchEntities:entityClass
                              withPredicate:predicate
                                fromContext:context];

    if(!entities || [entities count] == 0) {
        if (insertIfNil) {
            return [entityClass performSelector:@selector(insertInManagedObjectContext:)
                                     withObject:context];
        }
    } else {
        return [entities objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return nil;
}

- (NSArray *)fetchEntities:(Class)entityClass
             withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
               fromContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSString *entityName = [entityClass performSelector:@selector(entityName)];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                                   inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    if(predicate) {
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
    }

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *entities = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                               error:&error];

    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error executing fetch request for %@! \n\n%@", entityName, error);
    }

    return entities;
}
```

The top helper method is meant to help establish relationships during a large download. The problem I was having is that, even if say there was an `Account` object with an `accountId` of `1` in the persistent store (confirmed), it was only retrieving that object it half the time. I honestly cannot explain why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much debugging and trial and error, I've discovered that changing the predicate format from

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", entityUniqueIdentifierKey, value];
```

to

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %d", entityUniqueIdentifierKey, [value intValue]];
```

solved the problem. After studying the apple documentation, it seems that `%@` should work. So I am not 100% sure why this solved the problem.